# Highcharts SVG rendering issue with PhantomJs

Tags: node.js, email, highcharts, phantomjs, nodemailer

I am using phantom(6.0.3) to take screenshot of an angular page and send the html as email, using nodemailer(2.6.4). The angular page also has a few Highcharts(7.0.0) inside it. When the page is opened in a web browser in my local, QA and Prod env, all the chart looks as expected. But, when I send the same page in email(using phantom), the Highcharts inside the email in the local and QA versions look as expected, but the Prod version of the email shown some issues(screenshot below) - like the data labels almost goes to the edge of the chart and the legends start overlapping with each other! 
I have no clue as what might be causing these issues particularly in Prod environment, as I am using the same versions of all the above mentioned packages(node, phantom, highcharts etc.) in all the environments (local, qa and prod). 
The only thing I could find out while debugging the raw source of the email message is that the 'g' elements in the faulty charts has a different transform=translate(...,...) values, and that's causing the mis-alignment. But I cannot figure out what is the root cause behind this behavior, as I am using the same version of all the packages and only the deployment environment is different. Could it be any external module that is influencing this different rendering? Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Here are the screenshots of the Highchart trends from two different emails : 
1. Correct Label Positions -> 
[image]

2. Faulty Label Positions  -> 
[image]

3. Correct Legend Positions  -> 
[image]

4. Faulty Legend Positions  -> 
[image]

Comment: Hi Wenger, this problem seems to be very strange and hard to debug. Did you tried to set fixed positions of the labels?

Comment: Hey Wenger, I know advising another tech instead of the answer is a bit arrogant, but Highcharts 7 is very (last weeek) fresh and PhantomJS was a bit obsolete already in 2014, when the last release happened. Maybe you could migrate to `puppeteer` for more stable results, as it's using the latest Chromium to render pages.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I figured out that it might be related to some dependency libraries of phantomjs. It is working in my local and QA because in my local and  QA, the phantom js dependency libraries are still old, but the issue lies with the newer version of the dependencies.